# Assign a variable to each row in a CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file which contains this:

```
Person One,0
Number Two,0
Another Person,0
```

I need to append another number on to each line when the same person gets another score. The only way I can think of is assigning each of these rows a different variable so that I can append the score to that list.
Currently I have:

```
with open("scores.csv", "a+") as file:
        lines = csv.reader(file)
        for row in lines:
```

How can I assign each row a different name here while still keeping it as a list. For example, I want

```
p1 = ['Person One', '0']
```

So that I can do

```
p1.append(score)
```

Comment: have you checked out pandas?

Comment: how about opening your output file concurrently and writing the second number as you loop over each line?

Comment: @JamesTobin Pandas is a great tool, but imao would be overkill in terms of complexity for this application.

Answer (score 1):

You never want to do anything like "assign each row to a variable". You already have a variable that refers to all the rows, which is `rows`; you can reference an individual row in that list just by indexing it:

```
rows[0].append(new_score)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about opening both in/out files concurrently and appending and writing out in the same loop iteration?

```
with open(infile, 'rb') as fin:
    reader = csv.reader(fin)
    with open(outfile, 'wb') as fout:
        writer = csv.writer(fout)
        for row in reader:
            writer.writerow(row.append(new_value))
```

Comment: #freehand... not tested

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a list of gamers.

Just do

```
with open("score.txt", "r") as file:
     gamer = list(csv.reader(file))
```

Then you can add data with `gamer[1].append(32)` for example.